# Problem Passing a function reference in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda

The following line of code is throwing a compile error related to `Renderer::onScoreChange`. The reported error is:
Type mismatch.
Required:`(Int, Int) → Unit`
Found: `KFunction3<Renderer, @ParameterName Int, @ParameterName Int, Unit>`

```
var score by EngineObserver<Int>(20, Renderer::onScoreChange)
```

I'm trying to pass a function reference to a custom Delegate extending from the ObservableProperty class but not sure why its not recognizing the passed member function as satisfying the requirements of the function argument. Thoughts from anyone?

```
class EngineObserver<T>(
   initialValue: T, 
   val notify : (oldVal : T, newVal : T) -> Unit
) : ObservableProperty<T>(initialValue) {
   override fun afterChange(property: KProperty<*>, 
                            oldValue: T, 
                            newValue: T) {
        super.afterChange(property, oldValue, newValue)
        notify(oldValue, newValue)
   }
}

class Renderer {
   fun onScoreChange(oldVal : Int, newVal : Int){
      println("Score changed from $oldVal to $newVal")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miha_x64 is right. To make your code work, you have to do the following:

```
class Renderer {
    companion object {
        fun onScoreChange(oldVal: Int, newVal: Int) {
            println("Score changed from $oldVal to $newVal")
        }
    }
}

var score by EngineObserver<Int>(20, Renderer.Companion::onScoreChange)
```

Alternatively, if you have a `Renderer` instance you want to call that method on, you can do:

```
val renderer = Renderer()
var score by EngineObserver<Int>(20, renderer::onScoreChange)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Renderer::onScoreChange` is a member function which has `Renderer` as its first parameter.
You probably need a function reference applied to a certain instance: `renderer::onScoreChange`

Comment: Passing an instance, not the class itself, solved the issue.